# Regex for a Function Call?

Tags: php, regex

I'm looking to simply pull some quoted text out of a function call and was wondering if I could get some help with regex?

The string would look something like this:
'MyFunction("MyStringArg");'

I would, essentially, like to scan a file for any lines that call 'MyFunction', and then capture the string literal within the quotes.

**Follow-up Question**
How would I go about avoiding commented lines with this?

**Update**
I was able to solve my problem with:
`MyFunction\s*\(\s*"(.*?)\"\s*\)\s*;`

Thanks @devyndraen and everyone for your help!

Comment: What if the string `MyFunction("...")` occurs inside a string literal, or inside a comment?

Comment: Good luck. Function call syntax isn't regular :-)

Comment: What language are you examining?

Comment: @Platinum Azure, while I'm not saying this problem should be tackled by regex, but most regex-implementations can match more than regular languages. Besides, there's no such thing as a universal "Function call syntax": perhaps the OP is parsing/matching some home-grown DSL that _is_ regular.

Comment: I think the OP is using regex in the Right Way (tm) as in to solve a one-off problem, not putting this into production code.  So a 95% solution is probably good enough.

Comment: @Bart Kiers: Agreed, but it's usually a lot harder to match non-regular languages anyway, especially when you have to consider "other" languages you might not have thought of (e.g., to ignore comments and strings, which might have balanced and/or escapable delimiters).

Comment: @Platinum Azure, I agree with all that. I simply wanted to comment on the fact that a non-regular languages can be matched by modern day regex-implementations. Your remark suggested that modern day regex implementations are only able to match regular languages.

Comment: Do you know the function name in advance, or are you looking for all function calls?

Comment: Hey guys, thanks for the help!  I was able to make it work with one of the answers below (thx @devyndraen), however, since testing, I've noticed @anubhava posted a similar but slightly different response.  Could I get your opinions on which is better?  Also, now that you guys mention it, is there anyway to make it avoid commented lines?

Comment: @Sel: The more "correct" way to approach this is to utilize the [PHP tokenizer](http://php.net/manual/en/function.token-get-all.php). It gives you a list of syntax tokens in a php script. But it's a lot of work to traverse this and find the right chain of tokens which make up a funcion call. The regex is the easier, even if horribly inexact, approach.

Comment: For the record, you can use /\w+\([^"\)]*"([^"]+)"[^\)]*\)/ to match the first double-quoted argument of a function call of the form f(arg[,args]) even if whitespace or inline comments appear between the open paren and the first doublequote or after the second doublequote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what kinds of requirements for formatting you have, so I included the assumption that there could be any amount of space in the normal programming places there could be some.

The resultant string will be in the \1 backreference.

```
MyFunction\s*\(\s*"(.*?)\"\s*\)\s*;
```

http://rubular.com/r/qVsaqJS6gJ

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest this non-greedy regex with flag `s` (DOTALL in Java) (assuming there are no comments inside the parenthesis of this function call:

```
$regex = '/MyFunction.*?\(.*?"(.*?)".*?\).*?;/s';
```

If you use `preg_match($regex, $str, $matches)` then argument will be available in `$matches[1]`.

Answer (score 0):

To compensate for commented lines or blocks, you'd first need to filter the file to remove all comments before you apply the regex. For PHP, you could use the following:

```
$example='
line 1
line 2 // comment 1
line 3 # comment 2
// comment 3.1
# comment 3.2
/*
   comment 4.1
   comment 4.2
*/
line 9 /* comment 5.1
comment 5.2
*/';

echo '<h3>Example Text</h3><pre>'.$example.'</pre><hr>';

$regex='/
    (?x)
    (?:
        # single-line inline comments beginning at col#1
        (?s)
        (?:\\/\\/|\\#)
        [^\\n]+
        \\n
    |
        # single-line inline comments beginning after col#1 
        # preserve leading content
        (?m)
        ^
        (.+?)
        (?:\\/\\/|\\#)
        .*?
        $
    |
        # multi-line comments
        (?s)
        \\/
        \\*
            (?:.|\\n)*?
        \\*
        \\/
    )
/x';

echo '<h3>Regular Expression</h3><pre>'.$regex.'</pre><hr>';

$result=preg_replace( $regex, '$1', $example);

echo '<h3>Result</h3><pre>'.$result.'</pre><hr>';
```

which produces:

---

#### Example Text

```
line 1
line 2 // comment 1
line 3 # comment 2
// comment 3.1
# comment 3.2
/*
   comment 4.1
   comment 4.2
*/
line 9 /* comment 5.1
comment 5.2
*/
```

---

#### Regular Expression

```
/
    (?x)
    (?:
        # single-line inline comments beginning at col#1
        (?s)
        (?:\/\/|\#)
        [^\n]+
        \n
    |
        # single-line inline comments beginning after col#1 
        # preserve leading content
        (?m)
        ^
        (.+?)
        (?:\/\/|\#)
        .*?
        $
    |
        # multi-line comments
        (?s)
        \/
        \*
            (?:.|\n)*?
        \*
        \/
    )
/x
```

---

#### Result

```
line 1
line 2 
line 3 

line 9
```

Answer (score -1):

```
[^(]*("([^"]*)")
```

and then group number 1 will be the string in quotes.  You'll have to enquote it again yourself though.

(this is not highly scientific, as in it is likely to pick up some things that you don't want)

Comment: @MK, no problem. After noticing your rep just now, I figured it was a simple mix-up.

Comment: -1 the answer does not solve the OP's problem. It lacks correct escaping, does not match the required pattern, and will create empty results. Try using it against 'foo""' to see all three issues at once.

Comment: @Rob I omitted escaping intentionally because it is dependant on the particular engine.  I have no idea what you mean by empty results and your example doesn't match here.  So there.

Comment: @MK, 1. You need to escape the beginning and ending parentheses which appear just before and after their respective double-quotes by adding backslashes. This is universally supported and not dependent on any regex engine I know of and is critical for your solution to succeed. 2. Your solution will return an empty result for empty strings (i.e. "") which will require filtering after the fact to find useful results. 3. And finally, your solution as presented will match all of the following strings: '("")', 'foo""', '""' which isn't at all what the OP requires.

Comment: @MK, further your use of '[^(]*' is a no-op in that it will match *zero* or more non-left-parens.

Comment: @MK, It occurs to me that if your solution assumes Unix-shell or Vi(m) style regular expressions, you do not need to escape the internal set of parentheses but then, you need to escape the outer-pair to make them capturing. (Besides, shell or vi style regexs are a very special case and won't work in any other environments, so using them as your solution is questionable.)